# floating point accuracy in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

I wrote ***two*** code files in MIPS assembly for the expression below:

R(n) = (i to n) SUM { (i+2)/(i+1- 1/i) - i/(i+ 1/i) }

One code calculates the whole expression R(n) as summation and gives the result.

The second code first calculates first term, i.e., ***(i+2)/(i+1- 1/i)*** in a loop and then calculates the second term, i.e., ***i/(i+ 1/i)*** in another loop. It then simply subtracts the two summations.

Following are the results for the two programs for different values of ***n***:

Program 1:

```
 N        Result
-----------
10        5.07170725

100       7.41927338

1000      9.72636795

10000    12.02908134

100000   14.33149338

1000000  16.63462067
```

Program 2:

```
 N       Result
---------
10       5.07170773

100      7.41923523

1000     9.72259521

10000   12.31250000

100000   8.61718750

1000000  6.50000000
```

Program 1 is giving more accurate results (compared with Wolfram Alpha results for R(n)). Why does Program 2 gives odd results here for large values of ***n***? My question is related to floating point precision here.

**Note:** I am using single-precision numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have un=an-bn and you want sum(un)

lim an -> 1 when n -> infinity so the sum of P terms tends to P+cte_a, same for bn, the sum tends to P+cte_b

When you differentiate the two, (P+cte_a) - (P+cte_b), you should mathematically retrieve sum(un).

But with floating point, that's not what happens, because (P+cte_a) is rounded to nearest float. And the bigger P is, the less float(P+cte_a)-float(P) will be close to cte_a...

To convince yourself, try to evaluate these ops:

```
10.0f+0.1f-10.0f
100.0f+0.1f-100.0f
...
1.0e7f+0.1f-1.0e7
```

lim un -> 1/n when n -> infinity, so program 1 does a bit better...